# Tomcat service won't start in windows task schedular

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8

I have a batch script to restart Tomcat service and I have used that script in windows task scheduler that runs at a specific time, it worked fine during first few weeks but later on it didn't complete starting tomcat. The script I am using is

```
NET STOP Tomcat8
NET START Tomcat8
```

Logs I have are

```
catalina.2018-10-31.log
31-Oct-2018 04:00:01.145 INFO [Thread-78] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-80"]
31-Oct-2018 04:00:01.199 INFO [Thread-78] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["https-jsse-nio-443"]
31-Oct-2018 04:00:01.221 INFO [Thread-78] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]

commons-daemon.2018-10-31.log
[2018-10-31 04:00:03] [info]  [ 2356] Commons Daemon procrun (1.1.0.0 64-bit) started
[2018-10-31 04:00:03] [info]  [ 2356] Running 'Tomcat8' Service...
[2018-10-31 04:00:03] [info]  [17300] Starting service...
```

In services it shows tomcat as Stopped and I have to manually start it. I have no understanding regarding why this is not completely starting the tomcat service.

Java version is

[image]

Comment: perhaps the default tomcat port (80) is taken by another process? try to call the script: your_Tomcat_Dir/bin/startup.cmd or catalina.cmd  to start or shutdown.cmd to shutdown

Comment: that doesn't start tomcat as service rather in a command prompt window and I don't want that. plus If i run that same batch script manually i.e. by double clicking it, it works fine.